# textbox is not taking given full string

Tags: c#, html, selenium

I am trying to input an email address in to a textbox, eg. dd@gmail.com,but it only takes dd@g.

this is html:

```
<input type="email" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid-email ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched" name="email" placeholder="Email" ng-model="Email" required="">
```

C# code

```
  var Email = driver.FindElement(By.Name("email"));
  Email.SendKeys("dd@gmail.com");
```

Comment: You seem to have a lot of Angular related attributes on that input element. Try removing all of the `ng-*` and try the Selenium test again - does the entire text get entered this time (ignore whether the test passes or not. We need to know if the text is inputted correctly)? It's worth doing to remove Angular from the equation.

Comment: i am doing testing as tester so i can not change the html, is there any other way?

Comment: Get the developer to change the HTML in order to remove those attributes. The problem is that, I can't see why your `SendKeys()` call is failing to send all of the text. That is the standard way, using Selenium, to perform this task. So it would be useful to remove those attributes in order to eliminate from the investigation of the problem. Can I ask, does the `SendKeys()` fail to send the text every single time? Also, what happens if you manually type the email into that field? Does that work?

Comment: Are you receiving any exception?
You can remove angular attributes with java script (or breakpoint the test, remove them manually with code inspector and proceed) but afaik it should not matter unless some class is disabling the field.

Comment: every time its send only dd@g , it means it only sends all character which are before @ and only one character after @.

Comment: There might be a length restriction on that field, which means only 4 characters are allowed to be entered into it. What happens if you manually type the email in yourself? Are you allowed to enter all of the characters?

Comment: @Piotroslav no i am not getting any Exception,

Comment: @JasonEvans manually i can enter full email, there is no issue with manual.

Comment: @JasonEvans when i removed all ng- , it works perfectly.

Comment: "i removed all ng- , it works perfectly." You will need to speak with the developer(s) about this. Looks like there is something Angular related which is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As a tester, I can say that developers often refuse to make changes only for the automation...

So, if they don't want to "fix" this, you can try to enter your string character by character like it's done manually

```
for (int i = 0; i < myString.length(); i++) {
    element.sendKeys(myString.substring(i, i + 1));
}
```